# Returning Formula Field Value of Currency Type Based on a Condition

Tags: formula-field, currencytype

Assuming I have these formula fields returning currency values:

```
formula_field1__c : (currency1__c * currency2__c)
formula_field2__c : (currency3__c * currency2__c)
```

*Note that currency3__c is also a formula field:

```
currency3__c: (currency4__c - currency1__c)
```

Now, this is what I am trying to accomplish:

Every time a picklist value is equal to 'Value1', it must return the value of `formula_field1__c`, and Every time a picklist value is equal to 'Value2', it must return the value of `formula_field2__c`.

I created another formula field, `formula_field3__c` :

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(picklist__c,'Value1'),formula_field1__c,null) +
IF(ISPICKVAL(picklist__c,'Value2'),formula_field2__c,null)
```

I don't encounter any errors, but every time I save a record, `formula_field3__c` doesn't have any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula_Field3__c should probably read:

```
CASE(Picklist__c, 
    'Value1', Formula_Field1__c, 
    'Value2', Formula_Field2__c, 
    null)
```

The problem with your formula is that if you use "treat blanks as blanks", then you end up with something like "null + 0", which doesn't make any sense.